# Tkinter dataframe does not save what you add, doesn't list recent ones along with older ones (just recent ones)

Tags: dataframe, tkinter

I'm trying to get user inputs and I am new to Python. I am trying to create a dataframe where you save the item after you add a person using the dataframe. For some reason, when it gets inputted it looks like this:

[Here's the code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMArv.png).

```py
import tkinter as tk   
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk             
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from tkinter import messagebox

root= tk.Tk()
root.option_add('*Font', 'Calibri 19')
root.geometry("1440x900")
background = PhotoImage(file = "backtotheground.png") 

class My_GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.name = tk.Label(root, text = 'Name')
        self.name_entry=tk.Entry(root)
        self.info = tk.Label(root, text = 'Info')
        self.info_entry=tk.Entry(root)
        self.sub_btn=tk.Button(root,text = 'Add Person', command = self.add_frame)
        self.sub_btn.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.save_btn=tk.Button(root,text = 'Save', command = self.save_frame)
        self.save_btn.grid(row=1,column=2)
        self.load_btn=tk.Button(root,text = 'Load', command = self.load_frame)
        self.load_btn.grid(row=1,column=5)
        self.delete_btn=tk.Button(root,text = 'Delete Person', command = self.delete_frame, compound=tk.CENTER)
        self.delete_btn.grid(row=100,column=6)

 def add_frame(self): 
        self.name.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.info.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.info_entry.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.names=self.name_entry.get()
        self.bio=self.info_entry.get()

        global params
        params = [self.names,self.bio]
        print(params)
        self.a = params

  def save_frame(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.a,index=['a','b']) 
        self.df.to_pickle("/Users/stantwiceforbetter/Downloads/Code/barbieworld/biography.pkl") 
        ftypes = [('Pickle File', '.pkl'),
                      ('All files', '*')]
        self.file = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=ftypes,defaultextension='.pkl')
        if self.file:
            self.a.save(self.file)
  def load_frame(self):
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
        scrollbar.grid(row=4,column=3)

        total_rows = len(self.a)
        total_columns = len(self.a[0])
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                self.e = Entry(root, width=20, fg='blue',
                               font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
                self.e.grid(row=5, column=j)
                mylist = Listbox(self.e, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set,exportselection=False)
                mylist.insert(END, self.a[i][j])               
                mylist.grid(row=4,column=2)

    def delete_frame(self):
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.master,orient=VERTICAL)
        listbox = Listbox(self.master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
        messagebox.showinfo( "Confirmation", "Are you sure you want to delete this person? This action cannot be undone.")
        sel = listbox.curselection()
        for index in sel[::-1]:
            index.delete('1.0', END)
showframe = My_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to make sure it displays the tabs not overlapped, the updated person is in a table with a bio and a person's name, and I want the table to include the older inputs as well (unless you delete one which I want to work.)

Comment: There may be intentdation errors since I had to remove a lot of comments while I coded this (I comment the older code but don't show them since they may be future code for future coding projects)

Comment: The overlapping is probably because you add multiple widgets to the same cell. Also, `row=100` would not have much effect unless there are other widgets in row 99,98.. so on. plus, you shouldn't expect people to fix the indentation, you should always try to minimize such errors so people don't have to waste time fixing them.

Comment: I didn't ask them to be fixed or anything. I just asked you to imagine it without these errors, not fixing it.

Comment: Start with removing `tk.Tk` from your class's inheritance. There can only be one Tk window working at the same time, if you need other windows use `tk.TopLevel`.

Comment: @vladimirgeorge How can people help you if they don't run your code?  Also, pls read on how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll try to help you out with this seeing as you are new to Python and because it hurts me to see this.

What you are doing wrong in your code, right off the bat, importing the same module twice.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
```

It is the same module except that you both import everything from it using `*` and get access to it when naming it `tk` (`as tk`). This is bad and not necessary. `from tkinter import *` is the suggested method for `tkinter`, so you will need to remove all your tk calls in the code (unless you want to keep `import tkinter as tk` and then keep all the tk calls in the code).

Second - `Tk()` should only be created once and shouldn't be called multiple times. (`root= tk.Tk()` & `showframe = My_GUI(root)`.

You have two options to solve this - 1. `class My_GUI:` 2. Completely remove root and make `MY_GUI` your `Tk` instance.

Third - `global` is a big no-no. And also, what is the point in you using global there?

Fourth - Syntax. There should be space from both sides of the equal sign unless giving a function argument

Fifth - When adding code to StackOverflow, make sure it is in working condition, to some extent. This includes proper indentation and removed missing files required (your background image and your pkl file)

Sixth -
Now about your issue with how it looks, check these lines:
`self.sub_btn.grid(row=1,column=0)`, `self.info.grid(row=1,column=0)` and `self.info_entry.grid(row=1,column=0)`. You are placing all three of those on the same exact spot.

Imagine the grid as a chessboard, what you did was take 3 pawns and put them on the same exact square. The same issue applies to your name field - `self.name.grid(row=0,column=0)` and `self.name_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)`.

Move those to different rows and columns and not on the same spot and it would look better.

Seventh - Work is never done in the window element itself, you should always add a frame and build on application on top of it.

Eighth - 79 characters per line is advised.

```py
import pickle
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class My_GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        # Main frame to add all the elements into.
        self.mainframe = Frame(self.master)
        self.name = Label(self.mainframe, text='Name')
        self.name_entry = Entry(self.mainframe)
        self.info = Label(self.mainframe, text='Info')
        self.info_entry = Entry(self.mainframe)
        self.sub_btn = Button(self.mainframe, text='Add Person',
                              command=self.add_frame)
        self.save_btn = Button(self.mainframe, text='Save',
                               command=self.save_frame)
        self.load_btn = Button(self.mainframe, text='Load',
                               command=self.load_frame)
        self.delete_btn = Button(self.mainframe, text='Delete Person',
                                 command=self.delete_frame, compound=CENTER)
        self.mainframe.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.sub_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.save_btn.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.load_btn.grid(row=1, column=5)
        self.delete_btn.grid(row=100, column=6)

    def add_frame(self):
        self.name.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.info.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.info_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.sub_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.names = self.name_entry.get()
        self.bio = self.info_entry.get()

        params = [self.names, self.bio]
        print(params)
        self.a = params

    def save_frame(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.a, index=['a','b'])
        self.df.to_pickle("/Users/stantwiceforbetter/Downloads/Code/"
                          "barbieworld/biography.pkl")
        ftypes = [('Pickle File', '.pkl'),
                      ('All files', '*')]
        self.file = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=ftypes,
                                      defaultextension='.pkl')
        if self.file:
            self.a.save(self.file)

    def load_frame(self):
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.mainframe)
        scrollbar.grid(row=4, column=3)

        total_rows = len(self.a)
        total_columns = len(self.a[0])
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                self.e = Entry(self.mainframe, width=20, fg='blue',
                               font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
                self.e.grid(row=5, column=j)
                mylist = Listbox(self.e, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,
                                 exportselection=False)
                mylist.insert(END, self.a[i][j])
                mylist.grid(row=4, column=2)

    def delete_frame(self):
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.mainframe, orient=VERTICAL)
        listbox = Listbox(self.mainframe, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,
                          selectmode=MULTIPLE)
        messagebox.showinfo("Confirmation", "Are you sure you want to delete "
                                            "this person? This action cannot "
                                            "be undone.")
        sel = listbox.curselection()
        for index in sel[::-1]:
            index.delete('1.0', END)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.option_add('*Font', 'Calibri 19')
    root.geometry("1440x900")
    showframe = My_GUI(root)
    background = PhotoImage(file="backtotheground.png")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I didn't touch almost nothing I didn't have to. Good luck with Python.